# Average of fractions: Weighted sum of numerators over weighted sum of denominators?

Tags: average, means

I am dealing with data corresponding to demands for $N$ products.  The data consists of demand $d$ of each product that vary by month, and the quantity $m$ of that demand that is met.  I also have different $d$ and $m$ data by store.  Generalizing, $d$ and $m$ vary by different "independent" variables (the product, the month, the store, and others).  I want an intuitive average of $m/d$, and the average will take place over different subsets of the data by freezing certain independent variables.  In case it helps, this is the SQL `group-by` function, with counterpart idioms in Matlab and probably other analysis environments.

I want to weight the averaging by a scarcity weighting, which is basically one over the quantity of the particular product that is ordered each month in central stores.  Since there are $N$ products, each $d$ and $m$ value will be weighted by one of $N$ different scarcity weights $w_i$.  In the simplest possible form, an average on two values for $d$ and $m$ would be:

$$
\frac{w_1 m_1 + w_2 m_2}{w_1 d_1 + w_2 d_2}
$$

I thought that it would be simple to show the equivalence with the usual weighted average:

$$
\frac{ w_1 m_1 / d_1 + w_2 m_2 / d_2 }{ w_1 + w_2 }
$$

It turns out that they are not equivalent. It's certainly not a geometric average.  It also doesn't seem to correspond to a [weighted harmonic average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean#Weighted_harmonic_mean).  Yet it seems so intuitive.  Can it be related in some intuitive way to a classically defined average?

The supply/demand problem that I used to provide context to the average is just an analogy, as the actual problem is different.  So while I understand why respondents may question the nature of the problem, it's the actualy math that I'm hoping to rationalize in terms of classical definitions of averages.

Comment: What you've got there is a [weighted mediant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)).

Comment: Thank you so much, Rahul.  That explains it completely.  I also looked back on analyses that I did in years back, noticing that mediant is also the averaging done for widget failure rate estimation from different populations of widgets.  **Can you please post your comment as the answer?**

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Rahul for the answer.  The average is known as a [weighted mediant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)).